# Coupled linear differential equations with additional terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[How do I find explicit solutions of x and y in this system?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKvBy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio : $g(t)=e^{At}g(0)+e^{At}\int_0^t e^{-As}f(s)\,ds$.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I contracted the constants into some letters:
$$x'=ax+by+3+e^{it}\\
y'=cy+ex+2+2e^{it}$$
We will start by solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ without substituting anything yet.
$$x'-ax=by+3+e^{it}\\
\left(xe^{-at}\right)'=(by+3+e^{it})e^{-at}\\
x=be^{at}\int e^{-at}ydt-\frac{3}{a}+\frac{1}{i-a}+C_1e^{at}$$
Now, we will solve for $by$ to substitute it into the equation in $x$, solve for $x$ again and set both expressions we have for $x$ in terms of $y$ equal to each other. After which, we can solve for $y$.
$$by=\frac{b}{c}\left(y'-ex-2-2e^{it}\right)\\
x'=ax+\frac{b}{c}\left(y'-ex-2-2e^{it}\right)+3+e^{it}\\
x'+\left(-a+\frac{be}{c}\right)x=\frac{b}{c}y'+3-\frac{2b}{c}+\left(1-\frac{2b}{c}\right)e^{it}\\
\left(xe^{\left(-a+\frac{be}{c}\right)t}\right)'=\left(\frac{b}{c}y'+3-\frac{2b}{c}+\left(1-\frac{2b}{c}\right)e^{it}\right)e^{\left(-a+\frac{be}{c}\right)t}\\
x=\frac{b}{c}e^{\left(a-\frac{be}{c}\right)t}\int e^{\left(-a+\frac{be}{c}\right)t}y'dt+\frac{3-\frac{2b}{c}}{-a+\frac{be}{c}}+\frac{1-\frac{2b}{c}}{-a+\frac{be}{c}}e^{it}+C_2e^{\left(a-\frac{be}{c}\right)t}$$
Now, set both expressions equal to each other:
$$be^{at}\int e^{-at}ydt-\frac{3}{a}+\frac{1}{i-a}+C_1e^{at}=\frac{b}{c}e^{\left(a-\frac{be}{c}\right)t}\int e^{\left(-a+\frac{be}{c}\right)t}y'dt+\frac{3-\frac{2b}{c}}{-a+\frac{be}{c}}+\frac{1-\frac{2b}{c}}{-a+\frac{be}{c}}e^{it}+C_2e^{\left(a-\frac{be}{c}\right)t}$$
This boils down to solving equations of the form:
$$\int F_0dt+F_1\int F_2dt=F_3$$
Just to be sure we can solve this, I will show you what we can do... We differentiate the equation until we have one integral and then we differentiate again and substitute the value of the same integral from the former equation derivative.
$$F_0+F_1'\int F_2dt+F_1F_2=F_3'\\
F_0'+F_1''\int F_2dt+2F_1'F_2+F_1F_2'=F_3''\\
F_0'+\frac{F_1''}{F_1'}\left(F_3'-F_0-F_1F_2\right)+2F_1'F_2+F_1F_2'=F_3''
$$
Just for your information, it doesn't have to happen that we only have one function times the integral of another in the equation; if all such functions but at most one eventually become constant then zero as we differentiate (i.e are polynomials,) we can keep differentiating and substituting until we get a clean differential equation.

Since only $F_0$ and $F_2$ correspond to $y$ and its derivatives, we should only consider the one corresponding to the highest derivative of $y$ to know the order of the resulting ODE in $y$. Since $F_2$ corresponds to the highest derivative of $y$ from both the original equation and the final one resulting from differentiation, $y'$, we get a $\underline{\text{second-order linear ODE}}$ in $y$ owing to the $F_2'$ term. Now, keep in mind that we will get some $\underline{\text{extraneous solutions}}$ because we differentiated the equation $2$ times.

The ODE is of the form:
$$y''+P_1(t)y'+P_2(t)y=P_3(t)$$
Since the ODE is linear, we have $y=y_h+y_p$ where $y_p$ is a particular solution to the ODE and $y_h$ is the solution to the homogeneous case:
$$y_h''+P_1y_h'+P_2y_h=0$$
Since the ODE is second-order, we will [reduce the order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order#General_method) first (by [integrating factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_second_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations), for example,) then apply the boundary condition $y'(0)=0$ and then solve the first-order ODE. Afterwards, we plug in the result into the equation for $x$ and apply the boundary condition $x'(0)=0$ by differentiating $x$ if necessary. Also, keep in mind that, plugging in the boundary condition after reducing the order might not allow us to directly solve for the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$, but it will give us an equation that relates the two and maybe after we solve for $y$ with arbitrary $C_1,C_2$ and plug in the (working) solution in the equation for $x$ and apply the boundary condition $x'(0)=0$, we get another equation in $C_1,C_2$ and can solve for both. Or, maybe we get a solution that's parameterised by a constant (one constant only since $C_1,C_2$ are related via the boundary conditions) which is totally fine too.

Comment: Sorry but is there an altermative to thismethod?

Comment: @HanshengZHU I am not aware of any alternative method but George Ivy's, which I don't quite understand. My method has the issue of the ugly algebra and that makes it inefficient and hard to apply for the general case, so I suggest you try to understand George Ivy's method.

Answer (score 0):

We can write this as the matrix equation
$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}'= \begin{pmatrix}-1.442 & -0.842\\ -0.301 & -0.23 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} 3+ e^{it} \\ 2+ 2e^{it}\end{pmatrix}$.

That can be written as "X'= AX+ B" with X, A, and B the matrices above. If these were numbers we would first solve the 'associated homogeneous equation', X'= AX to X'/X= A so that log(X)= At+ C, $X= e^{At+C}= C'e^{At}$ where $C'= e^C$.  we would then find a function that satisfies the entire equation.  Since this is a linear equation we try $X= Pt+ Q$ then $X'= P= A(Pt+ Q)+ B= (AP)t+ AQ+ B$. We have AP= 0 so A= 0 and AQ+ B= P so P= B. $X= C'e^{At}+ B$.
With X, A, and B, matrices the only difference

is that A, C', and B are matrices.
In particular we start by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-1.442 & -0.842\\ -0.301 & -0.23 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: So how exactly do I apply the formula =′+  for matrices?

Comment: The only problem is that "e^(At)" for A a matrix.  If A is diagonalizable it's not difficult.

Comment: A is diagonalizable according to WolframAlpha, what do I do next? Also Im still unclear about how to find C.

Comment: In response to ′==(+)+=()++, I don't get what we're trying to do here. Also, are we ignoring the term B when writing down X'= AX and hence =^+=′^?

Comment: This is in response to "what do I do next?"  You diagonalize A!  If a matrix is diagonalizable then A has a "complete set of eigenvectors.  That is, there is a basis for the space consisting of eigenvectors of A.  In that case A= BDB^(-1) where D is a diagonal matrix having the eigenvalues of A on its diagonal and B is an invertible matrix with the eigenvectors of A as columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to Hansheng Zhu's question above
"A is diagonalizable according to WolframAlpha, what do I do next? Also Im still unclear about how to find C."

A is diagonalizable if and only if it has a "complete set of eigenvectors".  That is, the eigenvectors of A form a BASIS for the vector space.  In that case, A= BDB^(-1) where B is a matrix having the eigenvectors of A as colums and D is the diagonal matrix with A's eigenvalues on its diagonal.

The Taylor's series for e^x is 1+ x+ x^2/2+ ...+ x^n/n!+ ... For a matrix, A, and scalar, t, we can write e^(At)= I+ At+ (AT)^2/2+ ...+ (At)^n/n!+ ...
= I+ (BDB^(-1)+ (BDB^(-1))^2/2+ ...+ (BDB^(-1))^n+ ...

Notice that (BAB^(-1))^2= BAB^(-1)BAB^(-1)= BA^2B^(-1), (BAB^(-1))^3= BAB^(-1)BAB^(-1)BAB^(-1)= BA^3B^(-1) and, in general, (BAB^(-1))^n= BA^nB^(-1).

So e^(At)= BB^(-1)+ (BDB^(-1)+ (BDB^(-1))^2/2+ ...+ (BDB^(-1))^n+ ...
= B(I+ D+ D^2/2+ ...+ D^n/n!+ ...)B^-1= Be^(e^D)B^(-1).

But now, D is diagonal so D^n is the diagonal matrix with the nth powers of D's diagonal entries along its diagonal.  For example if $A= \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ then $A^2= \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}2(2)+ 0(0) & 2(0)+ 0(3) \\ 0(2)+ 3(0) & 0(0)+ 3(3)\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 \\ 0 & 9\end{pmatrix}$ and, in general, $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 &  3\end{pmatrix}^n= \begin{pmatrix}2^n & 0 \\ 0 & 3^n \end{pmatrix}$.

Summing all of those, $e^{Dt}$ is the diagonal matrix having $e^{d_it}$ on the diagonal and then $e^{At}= Be^{Dt}B^{-1}$.